# Как выровнять блоки в последнем ряду по левому краю?

Tags: css

Ширина блоков фиксированная, они должны выравниваться по правому и левому краю, кроме блоков в последнем ряду. Пробовал :after, но так как блоков всегда может быть разное количество, например когда остается 2 или 3 в последнем ряду, то позиционируется не совсем правильно.

```css
.content {
  padding: 50px;
}

ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  gap: 20px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

li {
  width: 240px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <ul class="products">
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пример 1

```css
.content {
  padding: 50px;
}

ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  gap: 20px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

ul:after {
  content: "";
  flex-basis: 240px;
}

li {
  width: 240px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <ul class="products">
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Пример 2

```css
.content {
  padding: 50px;
}

ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, 240px);
  grid-gap: 20px;
  justify-content: space-between; 
}

li {
  width: 240px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <ul class="products">
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо Вам большое!

Answer (score 0):

Если Вы уберёте свойство `justify-content: space-between;` у `ul`, то все блоки станут выводиться слева. Таким образов Ваши блоки всегда будут выровнены по левому краю

```css
.content {
  padding: 50px;
}

ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  gap: 20px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

li {
  width: 240px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <ul class="products">
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```